Can Compose Multiplatform navigate and change routes on Web while maintaining URL state?
I've been exploring Compose Multiplatform and went through the documentation, particularly Compose Multiplatform Navigation Routing. Despite the library being supported on the web, the docs mention that navigation and handling via routing is not yet supported.
Additionally, I reviewed Getting Started with Compose for Web and noticed that none of the demo projects showcase route navigation or changing the URL state dynamically. For instance, in a scenario where I click on a list item, I expect to navigate to that item's page with a new URL like "https://example.com/list/id", but this isn't demonstrated.
I've also checked the Compose for Web Slack channel but didn't find relevant queries. The documentation suggests other libraries like Voyager, Decompose, Appyx, PreCompose, and Circuit, but I haven't tried any yet.
Goal: I aim to run a single project on Web, iOS, and Android, meaning it should compile seamlessly across all platforms. Theoretically, I assume handling this through communication with native platforms is possible. Still, I'd appreciate confirmation on whether achieving this solely with Compose Multiplatform tools is not feasible at the moment.
If anyone has successfully implemented this or has insights into whether it’s possible with the mentioned libraries, please share your experience.
